# Conditions on a scheme to define the Chern character map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. With some conditions on $X$, we have a ring map
$$\text{ch}: K(X) \to A(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}$$
called the Chern character map, where $K(X)$ is the Grothendieck group of coherent sheaves on $X$ and $A(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the Chow ring of $X$ tensored by $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, if $X$ is a separated smooth scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$, then the map above exists.

What are the most general conditions we now know to impose on $X$ to define the Chern character map?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Fulton and MacPherson do this in the relative situation for a morphism $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ which is of finite Tor dimension. See https://books.google.fr/books?id=pR7UCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=fulton+finite+tor+dimension&source=bl&ots=wJHkgkbWfk&sig=ACfU3U0t1A114ll6AQqdLTkUUxE5NU33xw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidoeH3nOL4AhUGwYUKHQVSBpkQ6AF6BAgVEAI#v=onepage&q=fulton%20finite%20tor%20dimension&f=false

Comment: @Libli Thanks for the reference. I checked the book. The authors considered complex quasi-projective schemes (on page 119), and their Chern character (on page 136) is a natural transformation from topological $K$-theory of vector bundles to rational homology. Taking $Y$ to be a point, then $X$ can be a singular quasi-projective scheme over $\mathbb{C}$. In this case, there is a Chern character map $\text{ch}: K_{\text{top}}(X) \to H_{*}(X)_\mathbb{Q}$, but is this a ring map?

Comment: it seems indeed to be a  desirable property for the Chern character. Don't they prove it on the book?

Comment: No, they didn't.

Comment: If you restrict the map $ch$ to the $K$-theory of perfect complexes, then on any scheme $X$ the map $ch$ is a ring homorphism. This is a consequence of the properties of Chern classes proved, for instance, in remark 3.2.3 of Fulton's intersection Theory.

Comment: If you want this map $ch$ to satisfy some sort of Riemann-Roch Theorem, you would need some extra hypothesis on $X$, like locally embedable in a smooth variety. See for instance chapter 18 of Fulton's Intersection Theory.

Comment: Note however that it is hopeless to have the product property on the whole $K$-theory of coherent sheaves on $X$. Indeed, if $x$ is a singular point, then Serre's Theorem insures that $k(x) \otimes^L k(x)$ has infinite Tor-dimension and its Chern character is not well defined.

Comment: Finally, if $X$ is embedded in a smooth variety, say $M$, then the $K$-theory of coherent sheaves on $X$ has a module structure over the $K$-theory of coherent sheaves on $M$ (pull-back and tensor-product). In proposition 18.1 of Fulton's book, it is proved that some bivariant version of the Chern character respects this module structure.

Comment: When you said "... to the $K$-theory of perfect complexes, then on any scheme $X$ the map ch is a ring homomorphism," what's the target?

Comment: you should have a look at the precise references I gave in Fulton's book.